# Using df -h, i need to create an bash script that displays anything about 60% utilization

Tags: shell-script

I need to create an bash script that displays anything about 60% utilization

Comment: Please spend a few more words so we can properly help you. I think it makes sense to at least specify what your desired output looks like.

Comment: I'm a beginner, and I need to create a bash script that tells me when any of those sources get about 60% of utilization.

Comment: Update your question.

Answer (score 4):

No need for a script. It's a one-liner with a minimum of awk :

```
df -hlP  | awk 'int($5)>60'
```

If you want to change the output, just use awk 'print' :

```
df -hlP  | awk 'int($5)>60{print "Partition "$1" has only "$4" free."}'
```

And pipe it to your mailer :

```
df -hlP  | awk 'int($5)>60{print "Partition "$1" has only "$4" free."}' | mail -s "Disk usage on $(uname -n)" your_monitoring@your_provider.com
```

Happy cron :)

Comment: Could also use `awk '/[01]?[06-9][0-9]%/'`. But I like the `int` solution, didn't know it would work with the % symbol on the same position.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to institute a monitoring solution, such as Xymon (http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xymon/Xymon/4.3.21/xymon-4.3.21.tar.gz?r=&ts=1438001054&use_mirror=iweb) that can trend your disk usage over time.  You simply select the icon under the Disk colunmn and it will show you what it currently is and what it was when Xymon first was installed.  The problem with df is that, not only does it take a significant amount of time for machines with higher capacity, but it has to start all over the next time you kick it off.  The other issue with df is if you have NFS shares, it can hang at times.  You can use the -l switch to prevent anything beyond local mount points to be checked though.

If you must use bash, here's something to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash
ALERT=60
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
do
usage=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1 )
partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
if [ $usage -ge $ALERT ]; then
echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usage%)\" on $(hostname)"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df -h | grep '[6-9][0-9]%\|100%'
```

will grep anything with 60% or more usage